# posting to node from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Ok, I do not understand what is going here, works locally but not on my server.

I have a angular controller that post to my node server.

each time I try and run the function that triggers the post I get

> POST http://www.mysite.co.uk/mm3/back-end/savephotos 404 (Not Found)

Im honestly lost, ive rewritten the post 5 times I cant find the problem.

If anyone can see where ive gone wrong please help.

**angular controller**

*mm3\js\controller.js*

```
 //all photos've been pushed now sending it to back end
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $http.post('back-end/savephoto', $scope.photosToPhp).then(function (success) {
                            $scope.generating = false;
                            $scope.generateBtn = 'Generate';
                            //creating mock up gallery
                            for (var x = 0; x < success.data.photos; x++) {
                                var file = '/mm3/tmp/' + success.data.folder + "/out" + x + ".png";
                                $scope.gallery.push(file);
                            }
                            $scope.photosToPhp = [];
                        }, function (error) {
                        });

                    }, 800);
```

**then my node back-end**

***UPDATED: 
 So I have added a few console logs in my function to see where its going wrong and where it is getting to.
I keep getting:***

> test 1 function started error saving photo

*mm3\back-end\controller.js*

```
     app.post('/mm3/back-end/savePhoto', function (req, res) {
    console.log('test 1 function started');
    var folder = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 20);
    var photos = req.body;
    var counts = 0;
    var callback = function(counts){
        if(counts < photos.length){
            saveBase64(photos[counts],folder,counts,callback);
            console.log('test 2 save photo');
        }else{
            var counts = 0;
            var response = {"folder":folder, "photos": photos.length};
            console.log('test 3 save photo else');
            res.send(response)
        }
    };
    saveBase64(photos[counts],folder,counts,callback);
});

app.post('/mm3/downloadZip', function(req, res){
    var photos = req.body;
    var out =  photos[0];
    var test = out.split('/');
    var loc  = test.pop();
    var end =  test.join('/');
    console.log('test 3 function Generate zip file');
    console.log(end);
    var outName = '/' + end +'/mm3/MockUp.zip';
    var output = fs.createWriteStream(outName);
    var archive = archiver('zip', {store: true });
    var zip = function(photos, f){
        for(var t = 0; t < photos.length; t++){
            var file = 'mockUp'+ t +'.jpg';
            var from = '/var/www/html' +  photos[t];
            archive.file( from, { name: file });
        }
        f();
    };

    output.on('close', function() {
        var photos = req.body;
        var out =  photos[0];
        var test = out.split('/');
        var loc  = test.pop();
        var end =  test.join('/');
        res.send(end + '/MockUp.zip');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    });
    archive.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
    });

    archive.pipe(output);
    zip(photos, f);
    function f(){
        archive.finalize();
    }
});

function saveBase64(photo,folder, counts, callback){
    var result = photo.split(',')[1];
    var path = '/mm3/tmp/' + folder;
    var filename = path + "/out"+ counts + ".png";
    mkdirp( path, function() {

        fs.writeFile(filename, result, 'base64', function(error){
            if (error) {
                console.log('error saving photo');
            }else{
                console.log('photo saved');
                counts ++;
                callback(counts);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to be contained within photos[counts] ? I cannot see the data this relates to.

Comment: @FreddieColeman have updated the code with more information

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem:

```
app.post('back-end/savephoto', function (req, res) {
    // skipped some lines
});
```

change it to

```
app.post('/back-end/savephoto', function (req, res) {
        // skipped some lines
    });
```

Comment: Try changing both routes so that each has a beginning slash. Additionally, make sure that you're actually pointed at the localhost port (I assume you're running node locally). Maybe try appending `localhost:xxxx` to the $http.post route.

Comment: @WillCarron im on a live server, was working fine locally but live server it dose not work

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, the below:

```
$http.post('back-end/savephoto......
```

Becomes:

```
$http.post('/back-end/savephoto.....
```

In Node, the below:

```
app.post('back-end/savephoto.....
```

Becomes:

```
app.post('back-end/savephoto....
```

Then, you need to add a **console.log** under the Node route to see if it even is executed. This will narrow it down. Also, you can remove the **$http.post** call outside of the timeout to eliminate the obvious.

Let me know how you get on.

Shayan

Comment: Thanks Shayan, will try this morning and let you know

Comment: But you should get something in console right? If you are not getting it there, then there is a routing issue. So, anything in console?

Comment: Hey Shayan,  so Ill Update my question in a sec with updated node code. In my console I get "error saving photo" updating now

Comment: That is an entirely new issue. You have reworded the whole question to mean something else. The original question you posted has been solved. Close this and open up a new one. Furthermore, I suggest you clean up your code if you are going to ask on SO. Make sure it is stripped down to the bare minimum which demonstrates the issue.